# Sympy get quadratic and linear term from a expression

Tags: python, sympy

I have an arbitrary expression `E` in function of `x` and I would like to get the quadratic, linear and constant terms from this expression. How can I do it?

```py
import sympy
from sympy import sin, cos

def separate(expression, var):
    # ...
    return Q, L, C

x, a, b, c = sympy.symbols("x a b c")
separate(a*x**2 + b*x + c)   # Q = a, L = b, C = c

separate(cos(x), x)    # Q = 0, L = 0, C = cos(x)
separate(x*cos(x), x)  # Q = 0, L = cos(x), C = 0
separate(sin(x), x)    # Q = 0, L = 0, C = sin(x)
separate(x*sin(x), x)  # Q = 0, L = sin(x), C = 0
```

I've tried with derivatives, but when I have functions like `cos`, `sin`, `exp` and so on, my function breaks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe using `.coeff()`?

```py
def separate(expression, var):
    Q = expression.coeff(var**2)
    L = expression.coeff(var)
    C = (expression - (Q * var + L) * var).simplify()
    print(expression,' \t -->', [Q, L, C])
    return Q, L, C
```

Result:

```
a*x**2 + b*x + c     --> [a, b, c]
cos(x)       --> [0, 0, cos(x)]
x*cos(x)     --> [0, cos(x), 0]
sin(x)       --> [0, 0, sin(x)]
```

Comment: Thank you! I knew about ```coeffs``` when we have a ```Poly```, but I didn't know there was ```coeff``` for a expression